# Different requestBody Correct Method in Swagger OpenApi3

Tags: swagger, openapi

I have a form data like this:

```
{
  "form_id": 55426,
  "submission_id": 28,
  "status": 1,
  "user_id": "74285"
}
```

but sometimes `status` and `user_id` will not be passed and it will be like
and `user` and `type_id` will be there

```
{
  "form_id": 55426,
  "submission_id": 28",
  "user": true,
  "type_id" : 1
}
```

. So what is the correct method to define requestBody?

Is it correct to define like this,

```
requestBody:
        description: Check integration status.
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                form_id:
                  type: integer
                  example: 236089
                submission_id:
                  type: integer
                  example: 1
                status:
                  type: integer
                  example: 236089
                user_id:
                  type: integer
                  example: 1
                user:
                  type: integer
                  example: 1
                type_id
                  type: integer
                  example: 1
```

and in the tryout option, I should pass only relevant properties only? Or is there any option to describe differently multiple requestBody?